# Read and write Email using Microsoft Graph API Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I want to read and send email using Microsoft Graph API. I have tried using DeviceCodeCredentials and it is working fine but I want to read emails without any user interaction in the backend. By Using, DeviceCodeCredentials it asks me to login using my email id and enter the code provided.
below I the code I have written with ClientSecretCredentials which give me below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get access token
   at com.eclerx.email.AccessProvider.accessToken(AccessProvider.java:30)
at com.eclerx.email.AuthenticationBuilder2.main(AuthenticationBuilder2.java:55)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope 
User.read openid profile offline_access Mail.Read is not valid. Client credential flows must 
have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).
Trace ID: ac0c217d-72c7-4ba0-9472-16c711ceea00
Correlation ID: 4d9f5a16-e2e6-4c26-a30e-40e3aa89d53b
Timestamp: 2022-08-10 13:15:35Z
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
at com.eclerx.email.AccessProvider.accessToken(AccessProvider.java:27)
 ... 1 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS1002012: The provided value 
for scope User.read openid profile offline_access Mail.Read is not valid. Client credential 
flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application 
ID URI).
Trace ID: ac0c217d-72c7-4ba0-9472-16c711ceea00
Correlation ID: 4d9f5a16-e2e6-4c26-a30e-40e3aa89d53b
Timestamp: 2022-08-10 13:15:35Z
at 
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExcepti
onFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:45)
at
```

Code is as below

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder; 
import com.azure.identity.DeviceCodeCredential;
import com.azure.identity.DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Message;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.MessageCollectionPage;

import okhttp3.Request;

public class AuthenticationBuilder2 {
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "*************";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_ID = "**************";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "****************";
private static final String AUTH_TENANT = "*************";

private static final List<String> graphApiScopes = Arrays.asList("Mail.Read","User.read");
public AuthenticationBuilder2() {
}

public static AccessProvider initializeGraphForUserAuth() {

    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential =
            new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                    .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .tenantId(AUTH_TENANT)
                    .build();

    /*final DeviceCodeCredential deviceCodeCred = new DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .tenantId(AUTH_TENANT)
            .challengeConsumer(challange -> System.out.println(challange.getMessage()))
            .build();*/
    TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(graphApiScopes, clientSecretCredential);
    //TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(graphApiScopes, deviceCodeCred);
    
    GraphServiceClient<Request> graphServiceClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
            .buildClient();

    return new AccessProvider(graphServiceClient, tokenCredentialAuthProvider);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AccessProvider accessProvider = AuthenticationBuilder.initializeGraphForUserAuth();
    // get token
    System.out.println("token : " + accessProvider.accessToken());

    System.out.println(accessProvider.getServiceClient().users());
    
    
    User user = accessProvider.getServiceClient().me().buildRequest().get();
    
    System.out.println("My UserName :: "+user.displayName);
    
    final MessageCollectionPage messagePage = accessProvider.getServiceClient().me().messages()
            .buildRequest().top(3).select("subject").get();
    
    List<Message> messageList = messagePage.getCurrentPage();
    
    for(Message msg : messageList) {
        System.out.println("Subject -> "+msg.subject);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=2, the values are lowercased:user.read,mail.read,mail.send. Check if this is the problem

Comment: Same scopes are working when used with DeviceCodeCredential but still I will check

Comment: @questseekr - Can you please help me resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the client credential flow here, which means that you cannot dynamically request scopes. You must configure your required permission scopes on your app registration in apps.dev.microsoft.com, then you set the value of scope in your code to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.

[image]

please use string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet#azure-ad-v10-resources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider

Hope this will help , please let us know if have any question

Thanks

Comment: How to know who is Tenant Administrator

Comment: A tenant domain should be: admin@*********.onmicrosoft.com, To find the admin user, please check if any of your colleagues can find the Admin tile in their azure portal or you can ask if anyone receives some azure related emails like bills or notifications. or you can check in the azure portal with email admin@*********.onmicrosoft.com , hope this help thanks

Comment: Is there a workaround without using Application permission and just using Delegated flow ?

Comment: AFAIK , there is no-workaround as of now .